# Grounded mounting slot in Eagle

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

My PCB requires a mounting slot connected to the ground. I know how to use grounded mounting holes, but I can't figure out how to produce the desired result using a single slot. Is there a component in some library that I could use? Or do I need to define the shapes using the Pad (17) and Milling (46) layer? If so, how should I set up the shapes so that the fab house understands that the slots are to be plated?

This image shows what I can do:
[image]

This edited image shows what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: You know you can define your own components and put them in a library, don't you?

Comment: I do, but my question is more about how to set up the shapes so that the fab house understands that the slot interior is to be plated. Is it sufficient that the copper overlaps the milled area? Or do I need to instruct them explicitly?

Comment: iirc, I remember being able to get a similar result by putting a contour down and then putting a SMT pad over the shape on both sides. I used osh park, in hind sight, it was probably a miracle they did it how I wanted.

Comment: This is something you need to talk with your specific board house about. Different board houses have different requirements for plated slots, some may plate anything with copper around it, some may require explicit text callouts, etc.

Comment: To add on to @uint128_t, I have seen board houses ask for a distinct slot layer in the gerbers, outlining the slot that should be milled and then plated. As far as I know, the driving reason that some board houses may not support this is because milling and *then* plating is not a common process.

Comment: Usually the preference is for **drilled slots**. Many holes are drilled in an overlapping manner then plated in the usual way. Eagle lacks a way to specify this elegantly - intervention by the board house is required. See [this](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/what-you-didnt-know-about-eagle-slotted-holes/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this guide from Autodesk titled "What you didn’t know about EAGLE: Slotted Holes" could help:
https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/what-you-didnt-know-about-eagle-slotted-holes/

Answer (score 1):

> My PCB requires a mounting slot connected to the ground.

Eagle does not offer an tickbox for slots. You have to do this yourself.
You can do this in two ways:
 1. Create a rectangle on the outline/milling layer, and tell the fab house to mill it.
 2. Create a rectangle on the drill layer, mark it, and tell the fab house to mill it.
If you want plated slots, make sure copper overlaps with said rectangle, on top and bottom.

> Is it sufficient that the copper overlaps the milled area? Or do I need to instruct them explicitly?

You have to tell them explicitely. Some fabs offer online tooling for you to designate and mark outline or milling objects. 
Like Eurocircuits [PCB Solver](https://www.eurocircuits.com/pcb-solver-outline-editor/).

Beware that depending on plated or non-plated the capabilities of the milling can be different. In terms of minimum size (often 2mm), radius and precision.